# What is thread explosion in concurrent programming?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I recently heard the term `thread explosion` at a talk but could not entirely get what was meant by it. My guess is it has something to do with threads spawning unnecessarily for a specific task, eventually blocking and causing more threads to spawn. Can someone explain this a little better, maybe provide an example to help understand it?

Comment: I imagine it is about when you write divide an conquer algorithms such as summing an array/vector by dividing the range in 2 halves and spawn a thread to sum each half you will get a lot of threads quickly, resulting in a lot of memory usage and time wasted on creating and destroying threads compared to useful work being done. The problem is usually solved by making more lightweight threads backed by a limited number of persistent real threads.

Answer (score 3):

I have not seen this term in any literature on concurrency. According to a research paper

> **Thread explosion: Cyclic creation of a big quantity of threads.** We implemented a component that progressively creates 5000 running threads, each of
>   them sleeps for a second and terminates immediately after that - [Monitoring applications: An immune inspired algorithm for software-fault detection](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S156849461400386X)